# Are specific impedances for high-speed signals maintained beyond the PCB connectors?

Tags: impedance, high-frequency, routing, high-speed, trace

I found this [article](https://www.nexpcb.com/blog/trace-impedance) that describes the specific impedances that single/differential traces must have for high speed signals (using microstrips).

But what happens to these impedances beyond the connectors which the controlled-impedance traces are routed to? Are the impedances maintained? If not, then is it really necessary to design/route the traces with the specific impedances?

E.g., if I design a parallel RGB interface with controlled 50 ohm impedances and connect [a display](https://docs.toradex.com/104497-7-inch-parallel-capacitive-touch-display-800x480-datasheet.pdf), then are its ribbon and electronics designed so that they ensure the same 50 ohm impedances? If not, then all the hard work on the layout would be for nothing. In extension, this question refers to every device connected to a board designed with controlled impedances (USB, HDMI, LVDS, Ethernet etc.)

Comment: That depends on each individual connector and cable. Check the specs for each individually.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have given an example for a display (datasheet in link). In the datasheet it does not specify anything about impedance. I guess it is respected, but can I be sure?

Comment: If it doesn't say, assume it isn't respected.

Comment: @BrianDrummond And in that case, I can also assume that the display will not work, but I have a feeling that it is not the case.

Comment: In that datasheet I can find no input impedance spec. So assume high impedance. If your cable is long enough to need termination, you'll have to provide that yourself. I would assume the display WILL work given  suitable input signals measured directly at the connector.

Comment: Any characteristic impedances which do not match, will serve to degrade the signal quality. Designing properly will always help, regardless of cables and connectors - and could be the difference between the design working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the impedances extend from chips to PCB, from PCB to connector, and from connector to cables.

Cables are specifically manufactured with the required impedance, and these apply to all kinds of interfaces, including USB, HDMI, DVI, DisplayPort, SATA, Ethernet, CAN, RS485, even analog video interfaces such as VGA, component and RGB, composite, and S-video.

Answer (score 3):

> But what happens to these impedances beyond the connectors which the controlled-impedance traces are routed to? Are the impedances maintained?

Many times, if not most, yes!

> If not, then is it really necessary to design/route the traces with the specific impedances?

Hm, it's usually useful to at least make your PCB traces not work as antennas for the signals on them, so that you at least not interfere with yourself.

But: controlling the impedance of a cable is much harder (it's flexible! The acceptable cost per millimeter might be much lower!) than that of a trace, so that drivers and receivers for external cables do have to be designed with reflections and coupling in mind. But that also gets a bit easier when, at least between the chip and the connector, things are matched.

In reality, most of the things you find that are high bandwidth have a defined RF impedance: HDMI has 100 Ω (with a relatively big tolerance, low cost!), SATA cabling 100 Ω (with lower tolerances), USB3 superspeed pairs 75 to 105 Ω (low cost!), CAT5,6,7 ca 100Ω, Good Ole VGA 75Ω.

Answer (score 3):

Properly constructed cables *designed for specific types of interface* are indeed impedance controlled; if they were not then energy would reflect back from them.

Any such cable would *specifically state* both the cable impedance and loss per unit distance or the specific interface it is designed for such as USB, USB superspeed which will have the symbol on the connector. HDMI cables follow the same convention.

Other interfaces (Infiniband, LVDS for instance) are 100 ohm differential interfaces as are some fibre channel interfaces (it is nominally 150 ohms but I have had ICs where you could select either 150 or 100 differential).

Ethernet uses twisted pair (in various categories where the bandwidth is specified) and this [technical data](https://www.rm-electrical.com/technical-resource/cat6-cable-specification/) specifies the impedance.

So the short answer is yes, the impedance is maintained in the cable.